# implement iphone sms system

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i want to build an app that will look like iphone sms system
there is something build that i can use ?

Comment: Look like? Or work like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to build an app that LOOKS like the SMS system - here is a guide you can follow, using segmented images to create the bubbles:

http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/sms-bubble-ui-iphone-apps

It's another story if you want to implement the actual sms system. At least you can send SMS with a MessageComposer:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MessageComposer/Introduction/Intro.html

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it is a great idea.

Because you wont be able to get through the submission process on app-store (iTunes). Apple is likely to reject such apps